# How to combine lambda, vairadic functions and function pointers?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, variadic-functions

I have a nice idea which simplifies (for me) a lot of things.

Imagine you have a function that takes a function with x arguments which will be executed if an event happens. And to simplify this you have defined a new type with typedef, that is a function pointer.

```
typedef void (*HandlerFunction)(...);

void setHandler(HandlerFunction fun) {...}
```

now you use the setHandler function to... set the handler with a lambda function with additional sepcific arguments because you know that this function will always be called with these specific arguments.

```
setHandler([](int i, std::string arg) {
    std::cout << "Event with i=" << i << " and arg=" << arg << "!" << std::endl;
});
```

Now the question is... is this even possible in C++ and when yes, how?

Comment: Not exactly sure, do you want to bind arguments (with lambda) ? Do you want `std::function<void()>` ?

Comment: Does `setHandler` have to take a function pointer?  If it does you can't use a capturing lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 I want a behaviour like in JS were you don't need to define exactly what arguments you have in your declared function

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not exactly sure, but I need to save that function in something like a variable to execute it later on when an event happens

Comment: @Panakotta00 Do you want to accept lambdas that capture?  Returns from `std::bind` where you bind a object to a member function?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want a function pointer to a variadic function? That is not possible as-is.

Comment: @NathanOliver It doesn't need that, but it is good when it can do that. This will go into a library, so I don't exactly know if the user needs that or not.

Comment: @MaxLanghof It must not be a function pointer, It needs to be any kind of storage to save that function

Comment: A lambda evaluates to a *closure*, and an function pointer is not a closure (because it has no closed variables)

Answer (score 2):

**Variadic Arguments**

I figured it out, how to do it with an variadic argument list. The trick is to use an wrapper around the changeable function and use `va_copy`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdarg>

std::function<void (int, va_list)> foo = [] (int numargs, va_list args)
{
     va_list args_copy;
     va_copy(args_copy, args);
     std::cout << "Old Foo " <<va_arg(args_copy,int) << std::endl;
     va_end(args_copy);
};

void set_foo(std::function<void (int, va_list)> new_foo)
{
    foo = new_foo;
}

void wrapper(int numargs, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, numargs);
    foo(numargs, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main() {

    wrapper(123,456);

    set_foo([](int numargs, va_list args)
    {
         va_list args_copy;
         va_copy(args_copy, args);
         std::cout << "New Foo " << va_arg(args_copy,int) << std::endl;
         va_end(args_copy);
     });

    wrapper(123,456);
    return 0;
}
```

This results in:

```
Old Foo 456
New Foo 456
```

> I don't why the wrapper is needed, maybe someone knows. But it works :P

---

**Known Arguments**

You can use an `initializer_list` to pass variadic argument of an specific type to an variable lambda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>

std::function<void (std::initializer_list<int>)> foo = [](std::initializer_list<int> args) 
  {
    for (auto i: args) std::cout << "Old Foo: "<< i << '\n';
  };

void setFoo(std::function<void (std::initializer_list<int>)> new_foo) {
    foo = new_foo;
};


int main()
{
  foo({2, 4, 5});
  std::cout << std::endl;
  setFoo([](std::initializer_list<int> args) 
  {
    for (auto i: args) std::cout << "New Foo: "<< i << '\n';
  });
  foo({2, 4});
}
```

This will return:

```
Old Foo: 2
Old Foo: 4
Old Foo: 5

New Foo: 2
New Foo: 4
```

Comment: @NathanOliver: OP's lambda actually doesn't capture. Not sure if it is intended BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I missed that.  I saw the `[=]` and assumed it did.  Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Yeah, that goes into that direction, but there you don't have the arguments which are kind of important.

Comment: @Panakotta00  I extend my answer for your use case. Does it solves your question?

Comment: @Korni the problem is that I need a variadic argument in the foo function

Comment: @Panakotta00 I change my answer. Is it suitable now ?:D

Comment: @Korni we are getting closer but... I need not only integers... as I said I need a variadic function

Comment: @Panakotta00 I figured it out, see my edited anwer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have, in my opinion found the best solution.

I use this class as a container for the function:

```
#define C(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define F(a, ...) (std::function<void(__VA_ARGS__)>)[ a ](__VA_ARGS__)

#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class HandlerFunc {
private:
    struct function_b {
        virtual ~function_b() {};
    };

    template<typename... Args>
    struct func : function_b {
        typedef std::function<void(Args...)> func_t;
        func_t funct;
        func(func_t f) : funct(f) {};
    };

    std::unique_ptr<function_b> fb;
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    HandlerFunc(std::function<void(Args...)> f) : fb(new func<Args...>(f)) { };

    template <typename... Args>
    HandlerFunc& operator=(std::function<void(Args...)> f) {
        fb = std::unique_ptr<function_b>(new func<Args...>(f));
        return *this;
    };

    template <typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args) const {
        func<Args...>* f = dynamic_cast<func<Args...>*>(fb.get());
        if (f)
            f->funct(args...);
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid arguments to function object call!");
    };
};
```

And now it is possible to write code like this:

```
std::vector<HandlerFunc> funcs;

template<typename... Args>
void add(std::function<void(Args...)> func) {
    funcs.push_back(func);
}

int main() {
    int a = 321;
    int b = 123;

    add(F(C(a, b), int i){
        std::cout << a << b << i << std::endl;
    });
    add(F(C(=), std::string str){
        std::cout << b << a << str << std::endl;
    });

    int i = 0;
    for (auto& func : funcs) {
        if (i < 1) func(1234);
        else func("meep");
    }
}
```

The only one thing i want to have, is a #define that converts something like this

```
add(F([=], int i, std::string str){
    ...
});
```

into this

```
add((std::function<void(int, std::string))[=](int i, std::string str){
    ...
});
```

I'm very new to preprocessor stuff like that ^^

Answer (score -1):

I'm imagining you *want* to do something which looks like this:

```
Delegator delegator;
delegator.set_handler(handler);
```

Unfortunately, either the type of `handler` OR it's type signature (with `std::function`) have to be known when `Delegator` is declared.  Depending on what you want to do, this isn't so bad.  If it's okay for the user of your library to define a bunch of handlers in one go, and if it's okay for you to enumerate to the user which types the handlers should handle, e.g.

```
//The library user defines this
struct MyHandlers {
  void operator()(int){ 
    std::cout << "Event with i=" << i << std::endl;
  }

  template<class T>
  void operator()(std::string str, T t_){  
    std::cout << "Event with str=" << str << " and some class=" << t_ << "!" << std::endl;
  }

  void operator()(std::string str){ /** more code **/ }
};
```

Then you can do something similar to what you originally wanted to do.

```
//This would go in the library
template<class Handlers>
struct Delegator_t {
  Handlers handlers;

  template<class T>
  void do_stuff_which_eventually_calls_handlers(T t_) {
    std::string string = "string";
    if (/** condition **/) {
      handlers(5);
    } else {
      handlers(string, t_);
    }
    //The user's third overload never gets called.
  }
}
template<class Handlers>
Delegator_t<Handlers> Delegator(Handlers handlers){ return{std::move(handlers)}; }
```

And finally, the user can use your library and their `MyHandlers` class with the following

```
auto delegator = Delegator(MyHandlers{});
SomeClass some_class(/** some args **/);
delegator.do_stuff_which_eventually_calls_handlers(some_class);
```

Of course, if the user has to register various handlers at *different* points in time to the *same* delegator, the above method is useless.

Answer (score -1):

Some of the things you may do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void exec_handler(std::function<void(int, std::string)> cb) {
        static int cnt = 0;
        cb(cnt++, "from_exec_handler");
}

void handler1(int count, std::string name) {
        std::cout << "handler1\t" << count << " " << name << std::endl;
}

void handler2(int count, std::string name, std::string name2) {
        std::cout << "handler2\t" << count << " " << name << " " << name2 << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        auto handler_lambda = [](int count, std::string name) {
                        std::cout << "lambda\t\t" << count << " " << name << std::endl;
                        };
        auto clojure = [](int count, std::string name) {
                return handler2(count, name, "clojure");
        };
        auto partial = std::bind(handler2, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, "partial");
        exec_handler(handler1);
        exec_handler(handler_lambda);
        exec_handler(clojure);
        exec_handler(partial);
}
```

Output:

```
handler1        0 from_exec_handler
lambda          1 from_exec_handler
handler2        2 from_exec_handler clojure
handler2        3 from_exec_handler partial
```